# Code Editor in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-component

i am writing a small app to manage code snippets , so i want a component to display the code (keyword coloring , lines numbering ...) , so where to get this component and if it doesnt exist how to implement it .

**edit** : i dont want to write a code editor , only a component to display code with last features (keyword coloring , lines numbering ...) instead of plain text area
thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you've already considered this, but just in case you haven't... why not use Visual Studio C# code editor? It already has a code snippets feature since VS 2005. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392%28VS.80%29.aspx Why do you need to write your own C# code editor when existing editors already have the features you need?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free/open source code editor UI control for .Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968057/free-open-source-code-editor-ui-control-for-net)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For syntax highlighting check :

[Syntax Highlighting in Rich TextBox Control](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/duncanharris/syntaxhighlightinrichtextboxp112012005050840am/syntaxhighlightinrichtextboxp1.aspx)

[Syntax highlighting textbox in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/SyntaxHighlighting.aspx)

[How To Implement Syntax Highlighting In A WinForms Application](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/57072-syntax-highlight-in-c%23/)

Also you can check there must be some 3rd party controls.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting which has a lot of features.

Also, encapsulating http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about would be an option depending on your technology stack