# Create instance of Visual Studio editor control in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, textbox, editor

Do you know if it's possible to use the Visual Studio editor in .NET outside the Visual Studio isolated shell, for example in a Windows Forms application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Visual Studio Isolated Shell from the Visual Studio SDK.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb685691.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is, no.  You will have to use a custom control that you make or that you get from a 3rd party.  Here is a link to a good discussion on the topic:  [Free/open source code editor UI control for .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968057/free-open-source-code-editor-ui-control-for-net)