# C# code editor in HTML for ASP.Net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html5-canvas

I want to show C# Editor in a web page, Intellisence not required.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968057/free-open-source-code-editor-ui-control-for-net

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [Code Mirror](http://codemirror.net/), it provides support for C, C++ & C# among other languages.

Simple example:

```
<script src="/Js/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="/Js/javascript.js"></script>
<script src="/Js/xml.js"></script>
<script src="/Js/css.js"></script>
<script src="/Js/htmlembedded.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var element = document.getElementById("<%= txtCodeArea.ClientID %>");
        var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(element , {
            parserfile: "/Js/htmlembedded.js",
            stylesheet: "/Css/codemirror.css",
            path: "/Js/"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Load in the relevant `js` files, you find these in the `mode` folder from the download.

The script gets the element you want to use for code editing and includes the syntax highlighting/coloring for the .js files that you've included. `txtCodeArea` could refer to a multi-line `<asp:TextBox />`.